# Explanation for the following expected circular queue result

Tags: data-structures, circular-queue

I'm trying to create a circular queue and come across this problem.[image]

As you see, my answer is incorrect. I still don't understand the reason why it is the case, so let's go through everything again.

1. Create a circular queue of size 2
2. Enqueue 8, current queue: 8
3. Enqueue 8, current queue: 8, 8
4. Front: 8 (no change to the queue)
5. Enqueue 4, current queue: 4, 8
6. Dequeue, current queue: 8
7. Enqueue 1, current queue: 8, 1
8. **Enqueue 1, current queue: 1, 1**
9. Rear: 1 (no change to the queue)
10. Is empty: false (no change to the queue)
11. **Front : 1 (no change to the queue)**
12. Dequeue, current queue: 1

Following my analysis, the last `Front` operation should return 1 as the queue is `1, 1`. However, the answer is 8 instead. Did I miss something? Please explain this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It is required to check whether a queue is full before enqueueing. However, I didn't do so as I thought that circular queue is a form of infinite DS like drop-out stack so my answer is wrong.